# block or disable touch screen in ionic 2

Tags: android, validation, gps, ionic2, screen

I'm using the ionic 2 framework , I have an alert that validates if the gps is on or not and I want when the alert tells me that it is not on, disable the touch of the mobile device so that the user can not do anything until the gps is turned on.

*Is there any way to achieve this?*

**this is my method of validation :**

```html
gps(){



  
 let successCallback = (isAvailable) => { 

   if(isAvailable == true){

       //alert("GPS ENABLE");
   }else{

       alert("GPS DISABLE");
      
   }
  
 };
    let errorCallback = (e) => alert(e + "error");


  this.diag.isGpsLocationEnabled().then(successCallback).catch(errorCallback);
 

 
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Hopefully, someone has an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this by placing an overlay over the whole app. There is probably a cleaner way, but it worked for me.

HTML:

```
<div class="my-invisible-overlay" [hidden]="inputEnabled"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.my-invisible-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```